# How to load a php page with a 24 hours script running?

Tags: php

Here is the case first and then if necessary I'll post code:

**The script**

- I have a PHP script with a for loop, that for loop will take **24
  hours** to be completed.

**The problem**

- The page **doesn't load** because it waits until the for loop is
  completed.

**What I try to do**

- To show the page while the for loop is running

PD: *Please don't suggest Google nor PHP Manual, both tried, nothing found.*

**Here some code:**

```
for ($s = $getEnergy; $s < $maxEnergy; $s += $getEnergy + $sumEnergy2){

  $prodToEnergySql = "UPDATE ".$planetSolar." SET energy = ".$s."";
  $prodToEnergyResult = mysqli_query($db,$prodToEnergySql);

  $solarSQL3 = "SELECT energy FROM ".$planetSolar."";
  $solarResult3 = mysqli_query($db,$solarSQL3);
  $solarRows3 = mysqli_fetch_array($solarResult3);
  $solarEnergy = $solarRows3['energy'];
  }
```

Note that $getEnergy is 0 and $maxEnergy 1.200, increment 0,14.

**Alternative Code**

```
while ($getEnergy < $maxEnergy ){

     $prodToEnergySql = "UPDATE ".$planetSolar." SET energy = energy + ".$sumEnergy2."";
      $prodToEnergyResult = mysqli_query($db,$prodToEnergySql);

      $solarSQL3 = "SELECT energy FROM ".$planetSolar."";
      $solarResult3 = mysqli_query($db,$solarSQL3);
      $solarRows3 = mysqli_fetch_array($solarResult3);
      $solarEnergy = $solarRows3['energy'];
      }
```

Note: there are at least 8 variables needed to execute the script.

Comment: sounds like you are mixing sane uses for php. For one, no script should ever run for 24 hours. Your front end should not be processing whatever the back end is doing. Run them on separate scripts. Consider cron tab to process data at intervals that make sense. If none of this makes sense to you, maybe you're not ready to handle this task

Comment: you could just run it in the background on the server `exec("php script.php > /dev/null &");`

Comment: I see that useful but, will that script take the values of the necessary variables from the page who calls to it? Some variables are: user session and data obtained in the main page through sql.

Comment: "will that script take the values of the necessary variables from the page" - not automatically, no. You'll have to pass needed data explicitly.

Comment: It sounds to me that what you're looking for is called a "cronjob". It's much better for running PHP scripts in an interval. All you have to do with cronjob is to set it up to point to the file you want to run every X amount of time and just leave it for doing its job. Take a look here: https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: it seems to be what I should do, but the problem are the variables needed to do the cronjob

Comment: if the variables change, why not store the changes in a table and allow the cron job to fetch them when its called? Your code snippets dont make it clear what you're doing, at least not in a way that makes cron impossible